# Adding an Interceptor to an already built okHttp3 client

Tags: android, kotlin, interceptor, okhttp

Is it possible to add an Interceptor to an okHttp3 client that is already built? I use a singleton client and want to add an Interceptor to an already built client so I can add a custom cookie to the client without having to manually add it to each request.

Accessing the interceptors list directly from the client [returns an immutable list.](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/class-use/Interceptor.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the `newBuilder()` method is designed for:

```
val modifiedClient = client.newBuilder()
       .addNetworkInterceptor(MyCookieInterceptor())
       .build()
```

> You can customize a shared `OkHttpClient` instance with `newBuilder()`. This builds a client that shares the same connection pool, thread pools, and configuration. Use the builder methods to configure the derived client for a specific purpose.

See the first couple paragraphs of the [javadoc](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.html) for more details.

Comment: Yeah, not sure why I didn't try this to begin with. Brain fart on my part. Thanks!

Comment: Will client and modifiedClient both have the networkInterceptor? Is the original client modified by reference?